# Multivariate Test for Mean Equivalence

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mean, equivalence, multivariate-distribution

I am looking for an equivalence test for multivariate means (arbitrary or normally distributed).

Any suggestions or hints in the right direction are appreciated.

Comment: Look into intersection-union tests.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $X\sim N(\mu, \Sigma_X),~~ Y\sim N(\nu, \Sigma_Y)$ with sample sizes $m,n$, an equivalence test for the means would be

$$(\mu-\nu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mu-\nu) \ge \epsilon^2$$

where $\epsilon$ is the equivalence boundary you have chosen and $\Sigma=(\Sigma_X+\Sigma_Y)$. This is actually the Wald test, under the assumption of zero distance. You can find a very detailed explanation in Chapter 8 of [Wellek's bible of equivalence testing](https://www.routledge.com/Testing-Statistical-Hypotheses-of-Equivalence-and-Noninferiority/Wellek/p/book/9781439808184).